# Why does where predicate not work against cosmos db?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

The following code only works when the where predicate is commented out, on about line 6 of the below code.

```
var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<MyTasks>(
     requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions
     {
         PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(null)
     }
 );//.Where(p => p.Id == "1");

        var feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyTasks>(query.ToQueryDefinition());

        var results = new List<MyTasks>();
        while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync());
        }

        foreach (var item in results)
        {     
            Console.WriteLine($"Matched item:\t{item.Name}");
        }
```

If the where predicate is uncommented, no records are returned, even though there is a record with id="1"

Comment: When you say `even though there is a record with id=1`, what type of `id` in your db, because you validate it as string not integer

Comment: It's the default id for a cosmos document, a string. I just changed it to an int, but no joy

Comment: Does this work: `container.GetItemLinqQueryable<MyTasks>(..).ToList().Where(p => p.Id == "1")`?

Comment: Hi @dododo, I did try this earlier

Comment: and what was the result?

Comment: it requires a major code change, as ToQueryDefinition() complains about not being ienumerable

Comment: I don't say you need to leave it. You can remove all code after `Where` for the current diagnostic time and revert it back later. What you need to know is whether you can retrieve any data from `Where` if the source for `Where` will be not a cosmos container, but just normal .net collection.

Comment: Got there in the end. In case someone else finds useful: 
        var query = new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM Families f WHERE f.id = @id")
              .WithParameter("@id", "1");
             
        var feedIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyTasks>(query);

Comment: it's not solution, it's a completely different form

Comment: The real problem in my code was my being unaware that the cosmos db id field is case sensitive. For example, once I change my model from Id to id my original code worked, linq worked

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @thefunctionofnoreturn It will be helpful, if can you please share your Model declaration for MyTask.cs and data/document stored in Cosmos DB container?

Comment: @RitikaNalwaya, here is model:
public class MyTasks
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string? Category { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @thefunctionofnoreturn, thank you for sharing model detail. As I can see model class contains field as `id` of type string, want to know from where `Id` is getting saved into database. Can you please share document stored in your container? Also please share implementation of `OnModelCreating` method.

Comment: @RitikaNalwaya my Azure has all been deleted, owing to a subscription problem on my account. All cosmos docs have id field by default. To instatiate a class please see this article: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-instantiate-a-class-in-chash

Comment: @thefunctionofnoreturn if you found the solution yourself then write it as answer and accept it. Or if you consider this Q as low-reuse-value for others, then delete the Q.

Answer (score 0):

The Cosmos id is case sensitive:

```
var matches = queryable.Where(p => p.id== "1");
```

This will not work:

```
var matches = queryable.Where(p => p.Id== "1");
```